# java regular expression against curly brackets and digits

Tags: java, regex

I need a regular expression that will match only strings that contain zero or more parts into the curly brackets and zero or more digits. The curly brackets may contain any character. But outside of the curly brackets, only digits are allowed

The strings i would like to match are like the following:

```
 "34{yy}1232{blabla}"

 "{blabla}{xx}34{seq}"
```

I tried with this expression but it does not work as expected:

```
   "([0-9]|(\\{(.*)\\}))+"
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: you mean this https://regex101.com/r/rJ9aU8/4 ?

Comment: @geo: How should cascading curly brackets be handled? For instance `Foo{Bar{Qux}FooBar}Quux}`

Comment: I'm going to guess that you expected that the contents inside each brace were matched separately.  To start with, use the non-greedy * to match the contents inside the bracket -- *? not *

Comment: Define "but it does not work as expected". Your regex seems to be working fine, except I would change `.*` into `[^\\d{}]*` to prevent  digits and `{` `}` be matched inside `{...}`.

Comment: @geo I think we are talking to you only..

Comment: the problem is that my regular expresion matches strings like the following "34{yy}123bbccdd2{blabla}".

Comment: thanks Avinash, yous expression works like a charm, the problem was the greedy behaviour of my expression

Answer (score 2):

The reason your Regex doesn't work is because of the greedyness of the Kleene-star. Take for instance your provided example:

```
string: {blabla}{xx}34{seq}
regex:  {      (.*)       }
```

Thus the `(.*)` matches as much as possible.

Now if you want to capture every single number and every single curly braced part, you should make the regex non-greedy. You can do this by using the `*?` operator. The regex probably reads:

```
([0-9]+|\\{(.*?)\\})+
```

Resulting in:

```
string: {blabla}{ x x } 34   {seq  }
regex:  { (.*?)}{(.*?)}[0-9]+{(.*?)}
```

(added space for interpretation usage).